# How to disable button and enable while clicking on backspace using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a button to search, after click on search button it should be in disable mode for this i wrote the code as below,

```
$('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and I need to enable the search button after search results so it is also working fine but if I click on backspace it shows the search button in disable mode but it is occurring in Firefox only remaining all are working fine so i tried with backspace event to enable the button as below

```
$(document).keydown(function(event)
{
  if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) 
  {
    $('input[type=submit]', this).removeattr('disabled');     
  }
}
```

but it enables the button forever,wherever i require to disable, there also it is in enable mode .
So how can I solve this issue..
Thank u in adv....

Comment: don't you know how to disable in html?

Comment: Please read briefly and post comments...And if u know post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of document I think you should capture key on field and use keypress

```
$("#target").keypress(function(event) {
  if ( event.which == 8 ) {
     $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','');
     //event.preventDefault();// if you need to stop fire the default
   }
});
```

Comment: Instead of document how can i pass target name?

Comment: target is the ID of your search field

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using `attr('disabled','')` to remove enable

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) 
{ 
   if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) 
   { 
      $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled','');
   } 
}
```

Comment: Me too, it is just another solution :)